# What semantic tags go inside the header?

Tags: html, css, header, semantics

I am refracting code as a beginner and inside the header is 3 pages I can click on (I dont know what theyre called yet) and those pages are inside a  tag inside the  at the moment. What semantic tag can I use to replace the name  that won't mess up my header's appearance?

Comment: welcome to stack ,  please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If it's a nav bar you're referring to in your header, a simple

```
<header>
    <nav>
     ...Your nav code here...
    </nav>
</header>
```

usually makes the most sense semantically.

Comment: Thank you! Is <nav> the only semantic tag that properly is used for inside the header with the nav bar?